# Facebook FQL query hometown_location {city}

Tags: facebook-fql

I would like to create a FQL query where i would only get the `hometown_location.city` from the FQL and not all the hometown_location (array). is there a way to do it?

my current query is the following :

```
SELECT uid, hometown_location FROM user WHERE uid = me();
```

keep in mind that all my blank space are replaced by '+' so currently my query works.

My current result returns me an array which contain the city,state,country,zip,id and name.

The result has a little to much info for what i want to do with the result isn't there a way to only get the city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dot operator:
"hometown_location.city" should work

So your query would be:

```
SELECT uid, hometown_location.city FROM user WHERE uid = me();
```